# Align points on a disk

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

I have two $2D$ points $A$ and $B$ on a disk of center $O$ and a point $C$ outside the disk. I would like to find the rotation of the disk to align $A, B$ and $C$.

I don't really know how to tackle this problem.

Comment: The points A and B rotate and translate with the disk?

Comment: Are you conscious that there are an infinite number of solutions ? Among them, there exist 1) a solution with a rotation only (no translation) 2) an infinite number of soltions with translation only (no need for a rotation).

Comment: @JeanMarie I didn't realise that a solution without a translation existed. In that case I am interested in this one, ie rotation only. I will edit my question.

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães yes

Comment: Even if you are interested by the solution with a rotation only, you nevertheless need a description of your points with polar coordinates ; $(r_A, \theta_A)$, $(r_B, \theta_B)$,... Have you learned them ?

Comment: Have you tried using Cartesian coordinates? Find expressions for the rotated coordinates and write down an equation expressing that your three points are collinear.

Comment: You could try to write down an equation of the line connecting $A$ and $B$, depending on the original coordinates and the rotation angle $\varphi$. Then assume that $C$ lies on that line and solve for $\varphi$.

Comment: There are two rotation solutions, one with $B$ between $A$ and $C$ and the other with $A$ between $B$ and $C$